# mysql - subtracting values from foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `ITEM(id, description)` and `STOCK(id, qty, timestamp, item_id)` where `item_id` is a foreign key mapped to `ITEM`.

I am presenting the `ITEM` table with column `qty` that I get when adding the `qty` of all the stock of an item.

Now, I need to subtract items. In order to do that, I need to subtract from the `qty` of stock.

What is the query for this given that the stock with the oldest `timestamp` should be prioritized to be subtracted and that once the `qty` reaches 0, the remaining should be subtracted from the other stocks?

P.S.: I'm planning to create a procedure for MySQL so that I'll call it when I need to do that.

Comment: This query is one of the general pattern "Select oldest record from table" and it comes up a lot (similar to "select most recent" but it's the same thing with a MIN date instead of a MAX date if you want to look at "select most recent" solutions). Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807967/mysql-select-oldest-record-for-each-user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125996/how-to-select-oldest-date-from-mysql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826830/get-the-oldest-datetime-value-with-mysql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084061/select-the-earliest-and-latest-dates

Comment: @CaiusJard I am able to "select the oldest/newest record from the table" but I'm asking how to subtract from the oldest given that when the thing to subtract reaches zero, the other rows should takeover.

Comment: If you're writing a procedure, you'll be processing the rows in date descending order, with a cursor, reducing quantity of a row and updating as you go? If you have qty on 3 rows as 10,20,30 and the demand is 45, then 10 and 20 will be 0 and 30 will come to rest at 15 when the cursor has done looping/subtracting qty? Cursors are a mixed blessing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745165/looping-over-result-sets-in-mysql - Personally, i'd do it in the front end language, but you did seem to imply it was to be done 100% in MySQL